# Transport security between Metro service and WCF client

Tags: java, .net, wcf, web-services, ssl

**UPDATED**

I have a Metro 2.1.1 WebService secured with the mechanism `Transport Security (SSL)`. I want to access this service with a .NET 3.5+ WCF client. I found [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/2ea7a7a1-d97b-443d-8ea3-f2d5526643a7/) which solves the same problem problem, however I was still unable to make a working client. I think I'm mixing up stuff in the client config.

Comment: This means that WSDL from Metro service contains some security combination which cannot be configured via available bindings. The needed security configuration is probably visible in the config comment but just in case of some special requirement post the whole security assertion from your WSDL to your question so we can try to find binding configuration you need.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka Thanks for you response! I added the WSDL to the question.

Comment: The FaultException is thrown by the Metro service. It is the Metro service that is looking for a particular header in the soap message created by the WCF ClientBase class. If you have access to a working client that invokes this Metro service, you can use a tool like Charles or Fiddler (its kinda tricky to listen on SSL traffic but it can be done) to capture the soap message being sent by the working client and compare it with the soap generated by WCF.

Comment: @Sixto Saez I made a Java Client that calls the above webservice successfully. I tried to capture HTTPS traffic, but the webservice calls just happen in the background, so nothing gets displayed in Fiddler. I can only capture HTTPS if I open a page that is protected with HTTPS.

Comment: The link below may help getting Fiddler setup. If that doesn't work, you may try looking at the commercial Charles product. Another idea, do the java client and service have a configuration option that logs the soap message sent and received? That may be easier than trying to Fiddler. Link: http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp

Comment: @Sixto Saez I was following the same steps before and it resulted what I wrote last time. I think to capture HTTPS this way, the service call has to be browser traffic. At the moment, I have a Servlet in the client that calls the service, so I think that is not browser traffic, therefore Fiddler does not capture what I need. I will check if I can log SOAP messages.

Comment: @Sixto Saez Oh I can log them! http://metro.java.net/guide/Logging.html#Dumping_SOAP_messages_on_client. I will update you tomorrow.

Comment: Good news! You can disregard this comment>>> I know WCF can be configured to trace message processing at either the client or the service. Sounds like the only option is to see if a Metro-based service can configure to log incoming soap messages. If that works then you can configure the WCF client to log the messages it sends to the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Client Code**:

```
//IMPORTANT - THIS LINE IS ONLY FOR TESTING PURPOSES!
//This code is for accepting self-signed server certificate
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender_ws, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

//instantiate transport binding element, leave the defaults
HttpsTransportBindingElement transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();

//instantiate message encoding element, where message version must be Soap11WSAddressing10 to match metro web service requirement.
TextMessageEncodingBindingElement text = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
text.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11WSAddressing10;

//instantiate transport security binding element, with all the suggested values in app.config
TransportSecurityBindingElement b_element = new TransportSecurityBindingElement();
b_element.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = new Basic128SecurityAlgorithmSuite();
b_element.IncludeTimestamp = true;
b_element.KeyEntropyMode = SecurityKeyEntropyMode.CombinedEntropy;
b_element.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11;
b_element.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Lax;

//instantiate the custom binding and add the elements created above
CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding();
customBinding.Name = "myOwnPersonalCustomBinding";
customBinding.Elements.Add(b_element);
customBinding.Elements.Add(text);
customBinding.Elements.Add(transport);

//instantiate the client

Uri uri = new Uri("https://localhost:8181/test/hello");
HelloWebServiceClient  wsClient = new HelloWebServiceClient (customBinding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
//Call
richTextBox1.Text = wsClient.hello(textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 2):

The WCF team has released a set of interoperability bindings at [this link.](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20Express%20Interop%20Bindings) This [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2011/06/13/interop-bindings-for-wcf-released-in-codeplex.aspx) provides details on how to use them. One of the supported bindings is specifically for Metro based service. Haven't tried to set this binding up but it seems this scenario is covered.

Comment: I haven't test it yet but the main problem I see is that it is always presented as: "How to create interoperable service."  But the more common is How to create client fro XXX service.

Comment: Agreed, there always seems to be some quirk that in the service requirements that can be addressed with message contract shaping or behaviors and such but the learning curve to implement the fix is pretty daunting. I hope these new bindings makes easier to solve the simpler scenarios without undue customization. Thanks for your WCF contributions here, they've been useful a time or two :)

Comment: @Sixto Saez Sorry I did not have time to make progress on the matter, up until now, so I will make updates again. I just installed the extension, and I will have to find a way to put the certificate in the local store so that it will be visible for the wizard.

Comment: @Sixto Saez I've found WCF Express Interop Bindings to be kind of restricted when it comes to Security Mechanisms.